# Can we replace zookeeper with etcd in spring-statemachine?

Tags: etcd, spring-statemachine

What are the changes necessary to use etcd in place of zookeeper in spring-statemachine?

Answer (score 0):

Being honest I'm not sure as I'm not that familiar with it. If etcd allows to notify changes in a same way than zk then in theory it's possible. Beyond that it's just about having leader election and a way to store data.